# How do I make a form background translucent?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to use the code provided here (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/LovelyGoldFishDeskPet.aspx) 
to make a form background semitransparent using an alpha image. But I don't know how to implement the code. Can you help me, I just started my C# 3 hours ago. Please guide me.

Edit 1:

Look at the border of the inner image. I want my border to be like that.

[image]

Comment: You should probably focus on the basics first if you're only 3 hours into C#.

Comment: I know the basics, I learned c# 2 years back but don't remember much and I lack experience (haven't created many programs in C#).

Comment: So, you DONT know the basics. Simple. You say so yourself.

Comment: Can you define "Implement the code"

Do you not know where to start? Do you have Visual Studio installed? Do you have a new Windows Form project started?

Have you tried cutting and pasting this code in to your project and it didnt compile, or didnt work during runtime?

Comment: Based on your comment in the answers, it seems you have a program up and running. Can you explain better what isn't working?
Have you tried cut and pasting that code in to your project yet...

Comment: @Fuzz I don't know where to use that code to make my form background semitransparent

Comment: @Fuzz Yes I have copy pasted it in my form code window but it shows multiple errors. By the way i m on 64bit Win 7

Comment: @Fuzz do you want me to copy paste evrything in my code window here ?

Comment: @Failed_Noob
sorry, delayed response. Have been offline for a while :-(

64-bit Windows 7 shouldn't matter... 
Perhaps explain what errors it is giving and we might be able to assist there?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I know what you are trying to do now.
The code you were attempting to use is GDI+ based and uses Win32 calls...

If you can avoid that, then you definitely should.
The reason it probably won't build is because you havent included "using Microsoft.Win32" or something similar.

Either way, if transparent forms are what you are after there is a MUCH easier way that is supported by WinForms.

As per [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/XparentFormsCS10282007212944PM/XparentFormsCS.aspx), the trick is to set a forms transparency key to the same thing as the forms back colour.

Try this in your FishForm() or equivilant constructor:

```
this.TransparencyKey = this.BackColor;
```

I'm pretty sure that will do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

In the FishForm() function try placing:

```
this.Opacity = 0.5;
```

Inside. Normally that works, but I don't know how it will interact with the other drawing you have going on.

Comment: It made the entire form semi transparent. the fish is gone.  What I want to know is how to use the code given in the link to make the form simply semitransparent. And I am not working on the fish project

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you are trying to do, or what you mean.